# Maven cannot find symbol: class Asynchronous

Tags: java, maven, asynchronous, jboss

I'm trying to use the @Asynchronous annotation, but when I try to compile the project using maven the error: "cannot find symbol: class Asynchronous" appears.

As dependencies I added:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3.async</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-async-spi</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-alpha-3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Do you have an idea, why maven doesn't find the Asynchronous class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` and try again to `mvn clean install`.

The `provided` scope indicates that you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime and it is only available on the compilation and test classpath.

Also, according to the [`@Asynchronous`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Asynchronous.html) javadoc, the annotation was introduced in version `3.1`, while you're setting a dependency to EJB 3.0. EJB 3.1 is part of JavaEE 6, so a complete and proper dependency definition would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

More info:

- [Introduction to dependency management mechanism](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: @user3480264, see my updated answer. The problem is with the versioning

Comment: You should keep the "provided" scope, I think. Otherwise the dependency might end-up in the EAR/ WAR file.

Comment: It won't. The output format is configurable in Maven and doesn't have relation to which the dependencies are.